# How to access this key value in php?

Tags: php, magento, fedex

I have got the api response now i want to get only one value from the response.

[image: Fedex Response]

I want to this value from response [progressdetails] = > array();

$response = Mage::getModel('usa/shipping_carrier_fedex')->getTracking($data[$i]['track_number']);
                $trackings = $response->getTrackings()->getData('progressdetails');

```
            echo "<pre>";

            print_r($trackings);

            exit;
```

Comment: this array is dynamic and array is keys are static?

Comment: Try this : `print_r($array["_trackings:protected"][0]["_data:protected"]["progressdetail"])`

Comment: i  try this but this not work.

Comment: Please note that as soon as a technical problem has been posted on a volunteer website, it is no longer urgent. Questions so marked are not treated with any greater priority than others that come in on the same day.

Comment: This is an object, and the property you want is `protected` so you cannot retrieve it directly. Is there a getter? `$progressDetails->getTrackings()` perhaps? Use your autocomplete to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$response = Mage::getModel('usa/shipping_carrier_fedex')->getTracking(track_number);
$trackData = $response->getAllTrackings();
$progressData = $trackData[0]->getData('progressdetail');
$deliveredStatus = $progressData[0]['activity'];`

its work for me.
Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Response have Mage_Shipping_Model_Tracking_Result class object
you can review that class here

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Shipping/Model/Tracking/Result.php

```
$result = $response->getAllTrackings();
```

then to get tracking status as (4result will have array of `Mage_Shipping_Model_Tracking_Result_Status` objects

```
foreach($result as $tracking_status){

   $data = $tracking_status-> getAllData();
   print_r($data);
}
```